# jQuery - evenly distribute items on a line

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a way to evenly distribute a set of items on a line. 
My theory is

- that if I add up the `outerWidth` of the items
- then subtract that from the `innerWidth` of the container
- divide the remainder by the numer of items -1
- apply the remainder as a `margin-left` to all but the first item

but it doesn't work, and the last item gets pushed onto the next line. Am I missing something?

```
//example
<style>
    #outer { width:100%; border: 2px solid black; }
    .inner {width:250px; border: 2px solid red; display:inline-block; }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            outerWidth = $('#outer').width();
            oneWidth = $('#one').outerWidth(true);
            twoWidth = $('#two').outerWidth(true);
            threeWidth = $('#three').outerWidth(true);

            remainder = outerWidth - (oneWidth + twoWidth + threeWidth);
            marginToAdd = remainder / 2;

            $('.addto').css({marginLeft:marginToAdd+'px'});
        })
</script>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="one" class="inner">One</div>
    <div id="two" class="inner addto">Two</div>
    <div id="three" class="inner addto">Three</div>
</body>
```

Comment: isn't flexbox layout model a better approach? Have you tried it?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` is possibly what you're missing.

Comment: that's two things I's never heard of, and both look like they may be the answer to the problem I've just spent two days trying to sort out!!!!! Cheers,